# How to export all products?

Tags: export, prestashop, export-to-csv, prestashop-1.5

I need to export all products from prestashop 1.5.6 to CSV format, but when I try to do it from phpMyAdmin, I didn't have images products, child category, and article number.
My request is:

```
SELECT p.id_product, p.active, pl.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(cl.name) SEPARATOR ",") as categories, p.price, p.reference, pl.description_short, pl.description, pl.link_rewrite
FROM ps_product p
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product)
LEFT JOIN ps_category_product cp ON (p.id_product = cp.id_product)
LEFT JOIN ps_category_lang cl ON (cp.id_category = cl.id_category)
LEFT JOIN ps_category c ON (cp.id_category = c.id_category)
LEFT JOIN ps_product_tag pt ON (p.id_product = pt.id_product)
WHERE pl.id_lang = 1
AND cl.id_lang = 1
GROUP BY p.id_product
```